# Mongoose: "TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function" on connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to use [Mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/) with typescript 2.2.1, express 4.15.2 and node v7.7.2 but when i try to connect to mongodb it throws this error:

```
TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
at Socket.once (events.js:307:11)
at Socket.connect (net.js:943:10)
at Socket.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:76:27)
at Object.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:76:35)
at Connection.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:399:11)
at Pool.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:638:16)
at Server.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:384:17)
at Server.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:361:17)
at open (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:226:19)
at Db.open (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:249:44)
at NativeConnection.doOpen (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:58:11)
at NativeConnection.Connection._open (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:531:15)
at /home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:289:11
at new wrappedPromise (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:372:16)
at NativeConnection.Connection.open (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:288:17)
at Mongoose.connect (/home/fabian/Projects/Huis-Pils/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:242:47)
```

code:

```
 import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
 (<any>mongoose).Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

i just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue and it can be bug of Node 7.7.2

If then, it should be solved by https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/11762

Comment: Yes i believe so, I downloaded node v6.10.0 and i had no issues there. Good find!